# Determine whether a set is open or closed in R

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If I had a set such as $[1,\infty)$ or $(-1,\infty)$ how could I prove whether the sets are open or closed. I know the $\epsilon$ definition of openness and the fact that a set is closed if it contains all of its limit points. I want to start by fixing an arbitrary limit point in the set, but I need help figuring out what to do next.

Comment: As some answerers suggest, the following fact is useful: a set is open if and only if its complement is closed.

Comment: Can I say that if the set is not closed then it is open, since the only two sets that both closed and open are R and the empty set

Comment: And vice versa....

Comment: No, a set that is not closed need not be open. Example: $[0,1)$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran $[1,\infty)$ is certainly closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran $[1, \infty)$ is actually closed. $[1,2)$, on the other hand, or $\Bbb Q$, are neither open nor closed, and $(-\infty, \infty)=\Bbb R$ is both open and closed.

Comment: @Doldrums , no for example, $[1,2)$ is neither closed, nor open set $\mathbb{R}$. Hence if set in not closed in $\mathbb{R}$ does not imply it is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this. First, we should decide whether each of these sets are open or closed. Let's start with $[1,\infty)$. Here, it's best to look at the complement
$$
\mathbb{R} \setminus [1,\infty) = (-\infty, 1).
$$
Note that the above is an open interval, and is thus open in $\mathbb{R}$. Consequently, $[1,\infty)$ is closed. Alternatively, one can use a sequential argument. For $[1,\infty)$ to be closed, we must show that every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ of points *in* $[1,\infty)$ has its limit in $[1,\infty)$. More precisely, assume that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[1,\infty)$ converging to some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $x_n \geq 1$ for all $n$, it is clear that $x \geq 1$ as well. That is,
$$
x = \lim{x_n} \in [1,\infty).
$$
From this, we deduce that $[1,\infty)$ is closed.

Now, we treat the second set $(-1,\infty)$. Again, this is an open interval and is thus (by definition) open.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is a limit point of $[1,\infty)$ the there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $[1,\infty)$ converging to $x$. Since $x_n \geq 1$ for all $n$ we get $x \geq 1$ so $[1,\infty)$ is closed. [Alternately, $x \notin [1,\infty)$ implies $x<1$ and $(x-1,1)$ is an open set containing $x$ which contains no point of $[1,\infty)$. So $x$ is not a  limit point of $[1,\infty)$].  It is not open because $1$ is  not an interior point.  $(-1,\infty)$ is not closed because $-1$ is a limit point which does not belong to the set. This set is open.

Comment: The second sentence simply says that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \in [1,\infty)$ for all $n$ implies $x \in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: @nicomezi OK, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to those definitions of closedness and openness, $(-1,\infty)$ is **open but not closed** and $[1,\infty)$ is **closed but not open** since it contains all its limit points (which is only $1$). Another way to say it, is that **every convergent sequence whose terms lie within $[1,\infty)$, has also its limit within this interval.**